# How to make position:fixed div scroll horizontally

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a div with position:fixed, as the image below suggests.

I want it to be fixed vertically, but I want it to scroll horizontally with the rest of the content (notice the horizontal scroll bar).

Is this possible with CSS? Or do I need Javascript (in this case, how could I do it)?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: fixed position on x-axis but not y?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049845/css-fixed-position-on-x-axis-but-not-y)

Answer (score 6):

Old question, but I was also looking for a solution also, and found a nice simple jquery solution, and figured someone else might find it helpful if nothing else:

```
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $('#header').css('left', originalLeft - $(this).scrollLeft());
    });
```

with header being the div, and originalLeft being, well, the initial left:position. This also works if someone scrolls and then zooms out, such that it would go where you would want it to.

Answer (score 3):

You need javascript. Here you can read a tutorial (with *mootools*): http://www.rickyh.co.uk/css-position-x-and-position-y/. Here a similar question, solved with *jquery*: [CSS: fixed position on x-axis but not y?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049845/css-fixed-position-on-x-axis-but-not-y)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by css itself:

```
<div style="width:250px; height:250px; border:solid;overflow:scroll; overflow-y:hidden">
    <div style="width:500px; height:500px; border:solid;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the scroll bar appears right next to the div... I would want the scroll bar to appear in the bottom of the browser.