# How to make fixed header scroll X with content

Tags: html, css

If you take a look at: http://www.bendemeerwoolshed.co.nz

I have a fixed header. All fine there, however, if you reduce the width of the window (or look at it zoomed in on a mobile device) and need to scroll on the X axis, only the content scrolls. Is there a way to set position: fixed for just the Y axis?

Here is the CSS for the header:

```
header#header { 
   position: fixed; 
   height: 188px; 
   background: #fff url(../images/headerbgstrip.png) bottom center no-repeat; 
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049845/css-fixed-position-on-x-axis-but-not-y

Comment: try setting your width in pixels instead of 100& make it 1200px for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken care of with a simple piece of jQuery:

```
$('#header').css("left","-"+$(window).scrollLeft()+"px");
```

As a side note, I attached the header to the content in mobile devices as the static header was occupying too much real estate in mobile browsers anyway.