# Css position fixed for horizontal scroll but scroll vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have three `div` as below :

```
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="center"><table></table></div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

Now what i need to do is to keep `#left` and `#right` fixed for horizontal scroll and scroll `#center` only. This is working with css `position:fixed` for `#left` and `#right`. But the problem is when i scroll html page vertically i need all the `div's` i.e. `#left`,`#center`and `#right` to scroll. This is not working. Please anyone help me how to do it so that `#left` and `#right` scrolls vertically along with `#center` and remains fixed for horizontal scroll. I have no clue how to do it using css and make it work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this link, it uses a plugin called `scrollspy` to do the stuff. Pretty easy...

http://www.rickyh.co.uk/css-position-x-and-position-y/

Also, see this SO question: [CSS: fixed position on x-axis but not y?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049845/css-fixed-position-on-x-axis-but-not-y)

Thanks to [semir.babajic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1945688/semir-babajic) : here is the actual snippet. You will need jQuery.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('#header').css({
        'left': $(this).scrollLeft() + 15 //Always 15px from left
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there anything called `position-x` in css3??? Will it work in IE8 atleast. I tried to use the same in the firebug of firebox but failed.