# Fixed element ignores scrolling horizontally

Tags: html, css

I'm creating website and I have a small problem. At the end I set `min-width: 1200px`. When I change my internet browser to smaller resolution and scrolling horizontally, it does not affect to my menu items! How can I fix it?

```css
#page{
     width: 1200px; height:1000px;
}
#page #primaryMenu {
  min-width: 1200px;
  background-color: #151414;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
}

#page #primaryMenu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#page #primaryMenu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.65s;
}
        
#page #primaryMenu li a:hover {
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: #d10239;
 }
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <ul id="primaryMenu">
    <li><a href="index.html">STRONA GŁÓWNA</a></li>
    <li><a href="fryzjerstwo.html">FRYZJERSTWO</a></li>
    <li><a href="kosmetyka.html">KOSMETYKA</a></li>
    <li><a href="solarium.html">SOLARIUM</a></li>
    <li><a href="galeria.html">GALERIA</a></li>
    <li><a href="kontakt.html">KONTAKT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

I don't want to do my website responsive, I want to set it with `min-width 1200px;` to all devices. Its menu sticks to the top and I don't want to follow vertical scroll.Example: When i change web browser resolution to 200x200 and try to scroll to the right, my menu(list items) stays in the same position.

Comment: Are you sure you want a *min-width* of 1200px ? Don't you mean just 1200px for all devices ?

Comment: Yes, indeed my dear Friend

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get what you really want.

Comment: When i change web browser resolution to 200x200 and try to scroll to the right, my menu(list items) stays in the same position.

Comment: Yes, this is the `fixed` behavior. Full project won't help : we won't be fixing your project, we are helping your to solve one specific issue. I create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/411fcc00/1/) for you. Try to illustrate your issue there.

Comment: important to add: #page{
  width: 1200px;
  height:1000px;
} at begining. Try it now

Comment: So, do you what a sticky menu like [this](http://stickyjs.com/), or a regular menu like [that](http://bienvenue-travel.com/) ?

Comment: That sticky plugin almost do what I want. Look at their webpage, next set web browser to 300x300. Scroll to the right and menu moves with webpage. Thats great, but when You go down, menu stays on position and dosent move horizontally with webpage . Do you see?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

GOT SOLUTION IN JS: jsfiddle.net/vy8rbsv6/1

Comment: Please document your answer to help others.

Answer (score 0):

`position: fixed;` on `#page #primaryMenu`  : you are asking the browser to display your primary menu at a given x, y offset from the top left corner of the screen, scrolling or not.

Check [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position) about css position.

> **fixed :**
>
> Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to the screen's viewport and don't move it when scrolled.

If I understand correctly, you want a `fixed` position on the vertical scroll so that the menu will be `sticky` to the viewport's top, and `normal` positioning on the horizontal scroll so the menu viewed by scrolling.

I don't think it can be done in with a `css` only solution, but check theses questions :

- [Position element fixed vertically, absolute horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303173/position-element-fixed-vertically-absolute-horizontally)
- [CSS: fixed position on x-axis but not y?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049845/css-fixed-position-on-x-axis-but-not-y)

Comment: what instead of position:fixed should i use?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Is it a sticky menu that follow the vertical scroll, a simple top page menu, ... ? What is the expected behavior ?

Comment: Yes, its menu sticky to the top and It dont want to follow vertical scroll.

Comment: Maybe we don't understand each other, but to me, a sticky menu does follow the vertical scroll and stays displayed at the same spot on the page.   Anyway, I think @Karthi might be right on this one. Check his answer.

Comment: So how to make it follow th the vertical scroll?

Comment: In this case, `fixed` is the way to go ;) - and `width: 1200px` to set your menu to the proper size. Maybe a jsfiddle will help collaborate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you are giving `min-width` in pixels it actually taking `1200px` of the width.

If you are trying to achieve responsive design then use percentage.

Example: for `#page #primarymenu` use width as 100% or your desired value (in percentage). Then it will work just fine with all size screens

```
width:100%;
```

or

```
min-width:90%
```

Answer (score -1):

delete `min-width: 1200px;` and it will work fine

Comment: yet the nav does not change when i change the width of the screen!