# CSS image resize horizontally

Tags: css, image

```
div.image {
    background-image: url('http://www.seedsavers.org/site/img/SEO%20Images/0841-benarys-giant-zinnia-flower.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

I use the above css code to diplay a `500x500 image`. It shows well on screen however, is there a way that when I resize the window `vertically` then the image to `not resize` at all (scrollbars appear) but when I resize the window `horizontally` to `resize` too so that its new width fit the screen? Thanks

Comment: i think this is exactly what you're looking for-- [Here you go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049845/css-fixed-position-on-x-axis-but-not-y)

Comment: You can use any framework or media query to handle the size...or use % while specifying the width and the height.

Comment: use %'s? You can also use media queries...

Comment: I mentioned that too...

Comment: use `div.image {height:500px; width:auto; max-width:100%;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont specify width and height in PX Insted use %

```
div.image {
    background-image: url('http://www.seedsavers.org/site/img/SEO%20Images/0841-benarys-giant-zinnia-flower.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%; /* both as much you want */
}
```

Or else use media query.